# Domain goes to http by default and not https

Tags: apache, https, dns, xampp

I have a website hosted on a xampp server and a configured ssl and works great when I type in https://example.com but when I type in just domain.com it goes to http://example.com

Answer (score 0):

As I am hosting the website myself and running it through wordpress, I needed to go into the phpmyadmin database for the website and change the values of the url to be https://example.com from http://example.com